# How to apply a jquery function for children elements using a class as a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, each, blur

I have a function that fills some fields automatically based on zip code. On my jquery call, I pass a class .zip as the selector, but the problem is that I have 2 forms on the same page (each one is on a separate tab) and after filling out the zip code, both 2 forms are being updated instead of just the fields related to that form the user is.

So, how to restrict the address auto complete just to form where user is on? I thought about using `.each()` or `.find()` but I don't know how to adapt correctly my function.

Below, the whole function:

```
$k(".cep").blur(function() {

    //new variable to keep only digits
    var cep = $k(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

    //check if it's not empty
    if (cep != "") {

        //regex to validate zip
        var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

        //check zip format
        if(validacep.test(cep)) {

            //just fills with "..." before getting results from webservice
            $k(".logradouro").val("...");
            $k(".bairro").val("...");
            $k(".cidade").val("...");
            $k(".uf").val("...");

            //send query to the webservice json url
            $k.getJSON("//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                if (!("erro" in dados)) {

                    var stateToCode = {
                        "AC":485,
                        "AL":486,
                        "AP":487,
                        "AM":488,
                        "BA":489,
                        "CE":490,
                        "DF":511,
                        "ES":491,
                        "GO":492,
                        "MA":493,
                        "MT":495,
                        "MS":495,
                        "MG":496,
                        "PA":497,
                        "PB":498,
                        "PR":497,
                        "PE":500,
                        "PI":501,
                        "RJ":502,
                        "RN":503,
                        "RS":504,
                        "RO":505,
                        "RR":506,
                        "SC":507,
                        "SP":508,
                        "SE":509,
                        "TO":510,
                    }
                    var region = dados.uf;
                    //filling the fields
                    $k(".logradouro").val(dados.logradouro);
                    $k(".bairro").val(dados.bairro);
                    $k(".cidade").val(dados.localidade);
                    $k(".uf").val(stateToCode[region]);
                    $k('.numero').val('').focus();
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //if zip is invalid
                    limpa_formulário_cep();
                    alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                }
            });
        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep é inválido.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
        }
    } //end if.
    else {
        //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
        limpa_formulário_cep();
    }
});
```

As it's in brazilian portuguese, "cep" is the zip, "logradouro" is the street name, "numero" is the number" (this is just for auto focus after blur event, nothing else), "bairro" is the district, "cidade" is city and "uf" is the state.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you post some HTML or tell us if it's possible to distinguish between the to forms somehow (where they're in the DOM or do they have different attributes ...)!

Answer (score 0):

My solution using jQuery.parents() function:
This does not require you to have an ID. Just stops at parent form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.cep').blur(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.parents('form').find('.outputExample').text(self.val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="form_1">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Form 1</legend>
      <input type="text" class="cep">
      <p>Data: <span class="outputExample"></span></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="cep">
    </div>
    <p>Data: <span class="outputExample"></span></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: All forms have a generic class but all them also have a div to wrap the form itself and that div has an ID.

Comment: Second update : using parents, this lets us nest the form inputs inside divs  and tables within the form itself, jQueryparent() looks for direct parent, jQuery.parents() looks for all parents back to the dom.

Comment: Amazing! I will try =)

Comment: if this was the right answer please mark it accordingly :)